# How to use controller from parent directory in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a folder structure like this:

```
Controller/
├── API/
│   ├── APIController.php
│   └── APIFunction.php
├── OTPController.php
├── LoginController.php
└── HomeController.php
```

I'm trying to call a method from `OTPController.php` within my `APIController.php`:

`$otpController = new App\Http\Controllers\OTPController();`

But it returns an error:
`Class 'App\Http\Controllers\API\App\Http\Controllers\OTPController' not found in file /var/www/app/Http/Controllers/API/APIController.php`

Comment: `new \App\Http\Controllers\OTPController();`

Comment: @TsaiKoga It works. Thank you.